# Bootstrap 4 display multiple forms inline

Tags: bootstrap-4

Is there a way to easily display one form next to another in Bootstrap 4 ?
The following code doesnt work :-/

```
    <div class="bd-example">
        <form id="validate-form" class="form-inline pull-right" method="post" role="form">
            <input type="hidden" name="get_final_form">
            <input class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-outline-success" name="btn" type="submit" value="Validate" />
        </form>     
        <form id="new-form" class="form-inline pull-right" method="post" action="index.php" role="form">
            <input class="btn btn-outline-primary btn btn-outline-primary" name="btn" type="submit" value="New" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
`<div class="container">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item">
                <form id="validate-form" class="form-inline pull-right" method="post" role="form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="get_final_form">
                    <input class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-outline-success" name="btn" type="submit" value="Validate" />
                </form>
            </li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">
                <form id="new-form" class="form-inline pull-right" method="post" action="index.php" role="form">
                    <input class="btn btn-outline-primary btn btn-outline-primary" name="btn" type="submit" value="New" />
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Divide your space in two columns and put the respective form in it

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <form id="form1"></form>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
      <form id="form2"></form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.
It works with class "row" but not with the one I use "bd-example" :-/

Comment: @Phil Of course it doesn't work with `bd-example`, the docs clearly state that it should be `container > row > col-*`! https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works

Answer (score 0):

You are not using bootstrap column the right way.

do this:

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
However, I do have 2 different forms... You merge everything in a single one and this is not my goal.

Comment: Okay, your question is not descriptive enough.